# UIView postion changes in retina display

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I added a subview named LayoutView in my viewcontroller. LayoutView then added a subview named SectionView by the given code:

```
MSSectionView *sec1;
            sec1 = [[MSSectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(72, 95,172,145)];

            sec1.tag = 1;
            sec1.delegate = self;
            //sec1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            //sec1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
            [self addSubview:sec1];
```

In my normal iphone it will display as:

[image: normal iphone]

But In my retina display it will display as:

[image]

I tried autoresizing Mask. but the same result obtained.
How can i fixed the section view's position ?

Comment: which device it is ? i.e iPhone 4 or 5

Comment: second image is iphone 5

Comment: Do like this         if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale >= 1136){sec1.frame= CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
}

Comment: thank you.it will be easy for a single view. But i have a lot of views like this.

Comment: in that case you have to use the leftmarigin,topmarigin,rightmargin,bottommarigins

Comment: you mean autoresizingmask? i already tried that. but no change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29179/discussion-between-tendulkar-and-manujmv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your case resides in background image of frame rather the subview . Check the UIImageView displaying your background if it is resizing for background image . Counter check the frame of the Subview by using

```
NSLog(@"Subview Frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(subview.frame))
```

check that the screen sizes for both retina and non-retina is same . i.e. (either is should be 3.5 inches for both OR it should be 4 inches for both). Also appliy autoresizing on your background imageview

Comment: thank you. i didn't apply autoresizing in root viewcontroller. that's why autoresizing not works properly.